# Need help with layout of an organigram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

I have this drawing that I wanted to reproduce but I still can not arrange the nodes well and center it properly. Can someone here help me with this arrangement problem? Here is the drawing I wanted to reproduce:

[image: 1]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}\begin{flushleft}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every node/.style=
    {thick, draw=black, align=center, minimum height=50pt, text width=50pt}
}
\node(a1) {SALE};% start with left second level
\node[right=10pt] (a2) at (a1.east) {FINANCE};
\node[right=10pt] (a3) at (a2.east){WARE-\\HOUSE};
\node[right=10pt] (a4) at (a3.east) {M-PESA};
\node[right=10pt] (a5) at (a4.east) {EBU};
\node[right=10pt] (a6) at (a5.east) {MARKETING};
\node[right=10pt] (a7) at (a6.east) {OPERATION};
\node[right=10pt] (a8) at (a7.east) {CORPS SHOP\\VODASHOP};
\node[above=10pt] (top) at ($(a2.north)!.5!(a3.north)$) {Directeur de\\region};
%\node[below=20pt] (chini) at (top.north) {text};
\node[below=10pt] (b2) at (a2.south) {SALES};
\node[below=10pt] (b3) at (a3.south) {text};
\node[below=10pt] (b4) at (a4.south) {text};
\coordinate (atop) at ($(top.south) + (0,-5pt)$);% midpoint below top
%\coordinate (atop) at ($(top.north) + (0,-5pt)$);% midpoint below chini
\coordinate (btop) at ($(a3.south) + (0,-5pt)$);% midoint below a3
\draw[thick] (top.south) -- (atop)
%(chini.north) |- (atop) -| (a8.north)
(a1.north) |- (atop) -| (a8.north)
(a2.north) |- (atop) -| (a3.north)
(a3.south) -- (b3.north)
(b2.north) |- (btop) -| (b4.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX-SE. Creating all the nodes manually is a pain and you would not be able to aligne everything correctly. There are some packages that would help you a lot: `trees` library or `forest` package should save your life. Try and use them instead.

Comment: Hello SebGlav, i still have problem with package,eg for your code when i try to run it  this message appear that  "File `forest.sty' not found. \begin" i don't know how to add missing packages and it's not for this time only but I have always had this problem and when I find myself facing this problem I am blocked regardless of the package if it is missing. thank you for answers and god bless you

Comment: You probably could do it *by hand*, without the `forest` package, but it would be a good idea to have an updated LaTeX distribution if you need to write serious documents. If you need help with this, you can ask another question giving details on your configuration.

Comment: how to do it by hand how? i use miktex 2.9 and texstudio as compiler i try to update my miktex but after having finished doing this update there is no change.
I am using the complete version of miktex and when I try to search for another update version on miktex.org it only gives me the basic version.
if you have a link for a complete version please send it to me or if you have another solution i'm here, i'm listening.
thanks again for everything

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a proper solution without any *fancy* package, just using nodes with `positioning` and `fit` libraries. This may work on your configuration. Anyway, you would find a way to update your MikTeX, Desinstalling and reinstalling it works fine.

Comment: Now It works but I do the compilation online, for the update of my miktex I will try to uninstall it and reinstall it again because until then, the offline compilation always asks me for packages for forest.A lot of thanks to you

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it's ok with you. It'll inform other members that the question is not pending for correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={ draw,black,thick,
                            rounded corners=3pt,
                            minimum height=30pt,
                            inner sep=10pt,},
        chief/.style = {fill=cyan},
        sub/.style = {fill=pink},
        }
    \forestset{
        my tree/.style={                    
            for tree={
                forked edge,
                edge = {draw, thick},
                s sep=5mm,
                l sep=5cm,
                fork sep=4cm,
                anchor=north,
                text centered,
                },          
            },
        }
    \begin{forest}
        my tree
        % tree starts here
        [Directeur de région, name=DR, chief
            [SALES, sub]
            [FINANCE, sub]
            [WAREHOUSE, sub]
            [M-PESA, sub]
            [EBU, sub]
            [MARKETING, sub]
            [OPERATION, sub]
            [COPS SHOPS, sub]
        ]
        \draw[thick] (DR.south) |-++ (2,-2) node[sub,right]{RESSOURCES HUMAINES}; 
    \end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image: forest with a sole leaf]

### EDIT: Plain Ti*k*Z solution, without any package

Here's a solution without forest, without `trees` library, and without `chains`, if you can only do simple Ti*k*Z commands right now:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\tikzset{
        every node/.style={ draw,black,thick,
                            rounded corners=3pt,
                            minimum height=30pt,
                            inner sep=10pt,},
        chief/.style = {fill=cyan},
        sub/.style = {fill=pink},
        }     
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
        \node[sub](1){SALES};
        \foreach \content [count=\i from 1] in {
            FINANCE,
            WAREHOUSE,
            M-PESA,
            EBU,
            MARKETING,
            OPERATION,
            COPS SHOPS}
            {
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i+1}
            \node[sub,right=of \i](\j){\content};
            }
        \node[fit=(1)(8),draw=none](ens){};
        \node[above=3cm of ens,chief](DR){DIRECTEUR DE RÉGION};
        \draw[thick] (DR) --++ (0,-3) coordinate (aux);     
        \foreach \i in {1,...,8} \draw[thick] (aux) -| (\i);
        \draw[thick] (DR) |-++ (2,-1.5) node[sub,right]{RESSOURCES HUMAINES};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: V2 without forest]

Answer (score 1):

As suplement to @SebGlav answer:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \tikzset{
node distance = 4mm and 0mm,
     N/.style = {draw, thick, rounded corners=3pt,
                 inner sep=10pt}
            }

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes styles
    N,
if level={1}{fill=cyan!30}{fill=red!30},
% tree style
    edge = {draw, thick},
    anchor=north,
    forked edge,
    s sep=4mm,
    l sep=24mm,
    fork sep=18mm,
    },
% tree body
[Directeur de région, name=DR
    [SALES]
    [FINANCE]
    [WAREHOUSE]
    [M-PESA]
    [EBU]
    [MARKETING]
    [OPERATION]
    [COPS SHOPS]
]
\node (RH)  [N, fill=red!30,
             below right=of DR] {RESSOURCES HUMAINES};
\draw[thick] (DR |- RH) -- (RH);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]